# Camera Preview not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, barcode-scanner

I integrate [ManteeWorks scanner](https://manateeworks.com/) to scan upc, integrated successfully but it works on below Lollipop not working in lollipop & above and log clears suddenly. At last i got the log and it says like

**JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to release byte primitive array elements with an object of type float**

Can any one help me to come out from this problem? Any idea or suggestions or help are appreciated.

Comment: You have a bug in native code, either your own or a library you've imported. There should be more information in the logcat output, notably a native backtrace indicating the location of the problem.

Comment: Show the JNI code that's leading to the error.